# Can two different UINavigationControllers segue to the same UIViewController without having two NavigationBars appear on screen?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uinavigationcontroller

I have my storyboard set up like the following:

`[TabBarController] -> [NavController] -> [ \\ Arrive here  //]
                   -> [NavController] -> [  \\ from both  // ]
                   -> [UIViewController]`

As you can see I want both UINavigationControllers to be able to segue to the same final UIViewController, think of it like a Product page and the two tabs that segue are Main and Search for example.

My problem is when I seque to the final 'Product' page from either NavBarControllers I end up with two navigation bars on the screen. How can I achieve this workflow without having two navigation bars appear?

Comment: What is the purpose of two navigation controllers going to the same view controller?

Comment: @Xcoder I'm using navigation controllers so I can have a back button... the first nav controller contains a list of products and the second has a search page... both should allow the user to tap into the product to see details but should have a back button that either takes the user to the home view or the search view

Answer (score 0):

Probably, you have NavigationController prior to TabBarController, so from my point of view hierarchy is

```
[NavController 1] -> [TabBarController] -> [NavController 2] -> [ \\ Arrive here  //]
                                        -> [NavController 2] -> [  \\ from both  // ]
                                        -> [UIViewController]
```

In this case when you segue to any tab there are one navigation bar from first NavController 1 and second from NavController 1.
If you want to have only one navigation bar, you have to remove one of them.